# Firebird and Android JDBC Driver

Tags: android, kotlin, firebird, jaybird

have problem with Firebird. I have never work with DB. DB on server firebird 1.5.

1. Add lib: `firebird-full-2.2.4` to libs folder
2. Add this to Gradle: `implementation fileTree('libs')`
3. Add this to MainActivity:

   ```
   Class.forName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver")

   val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
   "jdbc:firebirdsql://jdbc:firebirdsql:193.###.###.13/3050:Scool",
   "###", "###")
   connection.close()
   ```
4. After start I have this:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: success.kneu, PID: 12219
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/resource/Referenceable;
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326)
>           at success.kneu.LoginActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(LoginActivity.kt:48)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.Referenceable
>           at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326) 
>           at success.kneu.LoginActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(LoginActivity.kt:48) 
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/naming/Referenceable;
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326) 
>           at success.kneu.LoginActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(LoginActivity.kt:48) 
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.naming.Referenceable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/success.kneu-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/success.kneu-1/lib/arm64,
>   /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400) 
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:326) 
>           at success.kneu.LoginActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(LoginActivity.kt:48) 
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823) 
>   2019-07-14 17:37:03.815 12219-12219/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID:
>   12219 SIG: 9

Comment: As you are using JDBC on Android please read: [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004)

Comment: If you have a `firebird-full-2.2.4.jar`, it could be a jar from a questionable source, because the normal distribution calls it `jaybird-full-2.2.4.jar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jaybird, the Firebird JDBC driver, does not work on Android. There is an [Android port of Jaybird](https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidjaybird/), but it is not maintained by the Jaybird team.

The error itself indicates a problem with loading the `connector-api` because of missing JNDI classes like `javax.naming.Referenceable` in Android. This would indicate that you are trying to use the normal Jaybird and not the Android port of Jaybird.

Try and replace your Jaybird dependency with one from the Android port.

Be aware though that in general you should not use JDBC drivers to connect to a database from Android. See also [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android).

Comment: "replace your Jaybird dependency with one from the Android port."  crash:  Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Error while dexing.

Comment: @AcauãPitta I'm not involved with the Android port, nor do I develop on Android, so I can't help you with that (btw a build failure is not a crash). But I repeat my advice: don't use JDBC drivers from Android, use a REST service to mediate between your application and the database.